# How to disable IIS localhost

Tags: iis, localhost

I'm trying to disable the IIS localhost from Windows, without success. The only thing I'm finding is, that you have to disable the IIS option that's found in the Windows-Features. I disabled it and restarted my computer multiple times, but each time the localhost is still the default IIS...

Is there anything else I can do? I'm a complete newbie on this topic, so please tell me if there's information missing in my question.

Also tried the advice in this article, without success. The terminal does say, that the service has stopped, but localhost is still the Windows IIS. https://www.names.co.uk/support/1607-how_do_i_stop_iis_via_command_prompt_.html

The page basically says to type the following in cmd.exe `iisreset /stop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems clearing the browser cache solved the problem.